# Slow moving auto parts data (public) from a US automobile company: where to find it?

Tags: usa, cars

I have found multiple papers which use this dataset (because it's apparently public) to set benchmarks in forecasting but they don't mention where it can be found. I have done some searching on my own and haven't been able to find it. Any help would be appreciated.
Some of the papers are:

[Deep AR paper by Amazon](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04110.pdf)

[Another one by Hyndman et. al.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251527888_Forecasting_the_intermittent_demand_for_slow-moving_inventories_A_modelling_approach#pfb)

[Another one by Amazon](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5940/2496779a6d92afd70a551b64be4356e1a781.pdf)